# How does meteor.js update template data?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Imagine, I have this collection post.js :

```
{
  text: 'Some long text, article',
  likesCount: 10
}
```

And template file post.html:

```
<template name='post'>
  Article - {{text}}
  The number of likes - {{likesCount}}
</template>
```

Whenever any user likes post, the data is reactively updated. Does **text** is also transferred from database to client on every **likesCount** update or only **likesCount** is transferred? This will cause high internet traffic where internet connection cost is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, Meteor only transfers the fields that change. You can confirm this for yourself with the Network tab in Developer Tools.

Comment: "As I understand it, Meteor only transfers the fields that change." That's correct. See https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-mergebox.html (especially the Limitations section).

Comment: I have tried to inscpect with Chrome Dev Tools. I updated likesCount from meteor terminal. But nothing appears in Network tab. Can you please suggest how to confirm what you are saying?

Comment: Please do some searching before you ask questions. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373648/how-to-view-meteor-ddp-traffic), or search for the many answers about inspecting WebSockets traffic.